# Urgent! Grub error: no such device

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7, grubrescue

I've been using Windows on my new computer for about 3 days, and now I decided to install Ubuntu.

Now, I keep seeing the `no such device` error when trying to boot it up. I made a dumb decision and installed the bootloader on the same drive as the Windows bootloader, and I cannot boot into Windows either.

I have two hard drives, one SSD and one HDD. I created a partition on the HDD, formated it as EXT4 and installed Ubuntu on it. I chose the SSD for the bootloader location.

After I booted from the CD a couple of times and decided to attempt to reinstall it, when it asked what I want to do, it said it did not detect any existing operating systems. I have checked the SSD from inside Ubuntu, and it seems that it still contains the Windows files, as well as a folder called `ubuntu`.

I looked all over the internet, and can't find anything of use. I am starting to panic, so I rather avoid doing anything else myself before getting a response from a more experienced user. I want to revert what I've done, and keep on using Windows. I would very much appreciate a fast response.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7229330/

Comment: Would it be a good idea to attempt the recommended repair? If so, which partition should I choose for `Partition booted by the MBR`? Also, what does MBR stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but it seems the Boot-Repair tool has fixed it.